# Angular 8: Pipe to hide past events doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, date, pipe

I created a checkbox in my template to hide all elements that have been taken place earlier than today depending on the `bookingEnd` in my JSON data. The `recent-filter.pipe.ts` pipe should filter all past events.

To my problem, I get an `error TS2365: Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'Date'.` in advance in the pipe and no data gets displayed on my template. The whole scenario works in pure JavaScript, so I think that `bookingEnd` is definitely a date object.

Can you help me why there is no data after applying the pipe filter?

**JSON Data:**

```
{
  bookingStart: "2019-10-27T23:00:00.000Z",
  bookingEnd: "2019-12-29T23:00:00.000Z",
  city: "Manhattan",
  confirmed: false,
  country: "UK"
}
```

**recent-filter.pipe.ts:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'recentFilter'
})
export class RecentFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(list: any[], checked: boolean) {
    if (checked) {
      const futureDates = list.filter(x => {
        return Date.parse(x.bookingEnd) > new Date();
      });
      return futureDates;
    } else {
      return list;
    }
  }
}
```

**bookings-table.component.html:**

```
<tr
  *ngFor="
    let item of bookings
    | recentFilter: checked
  ">
      ...
</tr>
```

Comment: You should compare dates by getting the timestamp, ie `new Date().getTime()` So you can use bigger than and smaller than operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error you get already tells you not to use > to compare dates
To compare them use .getTime() method

```
new Date(x.bookingEnd).getTime() > new Date().getTime()
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. But the returned objects are still empty. The error, it seems, is resolved!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that Date.Parse returns a number. The documentation says: [Date.Parse (Dev Mozilla)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

You should use `new Date(Date.Parse([YOUR_STRING_DATE]));`
but I would advice you to be aware of wrong string formats and null values will date parsing.

It would be event better to avoid Date.Parse with a more modern syntax for parsing [Date Parsing es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript) and then compare them using the getTime() function [Compare Dates es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)